# jquery ajax not working on iOS - seems NOT to be a cache problem

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax

I'm completely stuck for days now ... can anybody tell me why this works even on iOS …

```
  var setlist = {};
  setlist['title'] = $(target).val();
  setlist['ID'] = $(target).attr('data-setlist');

  $.ajax({
    url: "_store_title.php",
    type: "post",
    data: setlist,
    success: function(response) {
      location.reload();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }

  });
```

… while this doesn't:

```
  var songData = {};
  songData['songID'] = $(target).find('[name="songID"]').val();
  songData['setlistID'] = $(target).attr('data-setlist');

  $.ajax({
    url: "_add_song.php",
    type: "post",
    data: songData,
    success: function(response) {
      location.reload();
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }

  });
```

The .php-Files store the submitted data in a database. The code works perfectly on every device but my iPhone (iOS 12.1.4).

While testing and researching I found that 'setlist' and 'songData' carry the correct data (even on my iPhone). It seems to be the ajax-call my iPhone refuses to execute.

Of course I found out about that weird caching issue with ajax on iOS. The trouble is that none of the solutions for that issue work for me. What really puzzles me is that the 'setlist' piece of code works without any issues, while the 'song' piece refuses to work completely.

Am I missing something completely stupid? Or is this as weird as I tink? Any ideas?

Comment: what triggers the ajax to fire?

Comment: I suspect that your event handler that wraps the ajax might be what is failing, can you add an alert('it works'); at the top of each block of code and confirm that the alert works?  I've had similar issues in the past with iOS as well, but need more info to help you.  Your ajax looks good otherwise.

Comment: Hi Nicolay, here is how the ajax are fired:

$('html').on('change', '.js-storeTitle', function() {
    storeTitle(this);
  });

wich calls

storeTitle = function(target) { (code from above) }

and 

$('html').on('submit', '.js-addSong', function() {
    addSong(this);
  });

which calls 

addSong = function(target) { (code from above) }

Comment: I already tested by adding alerts. Alerting 'songData' shows that it carries the correct values. Alerting inside 'success' or 'error' inside the ajax doesn't show any result at all which lets me think that the ajax call is not executed at all. In the second case, that is. The first one ('setlist') works. Don't ask me why ... :D

Comment: Can you try adding a .always() in your Ajax and alert in there as well?

Comment: Tried it, and it results in, umm, well - nothing! No alert at all, not in iOS, not in any other device … beats me!

By the way: Thank you for your support! :)

Comment: Hmm, sorry I can't help more!

Comment: Thanks anyway! At least we can say the problem lies in the ajax, for whatever reason …

Comment: Have you tried appending a random query parameter to the end of your URL to rule out cacheing? '_add_song.php?random=123456'

Comment: Hi Nicolay, thanks again! :) Yes I tried that. I also tried 'cache: false',' headers: {"cache-control": "no-cache")' and '$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });'. Did not work. And if it did, it would still not explain why iOS should cache only this single ajax call while two others just work fine...